# The PHP function array_unique doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP and I want to remove duplicates.

I simply turned to the function `array_unique()` to create a new array and remove the duplicates.

Here's the code:

```
$unlink = array();
$unlink = array_unique($linkphoto);

foreach ($unlink as $link) {
    echo $link, "<br />";
}
```

Still it shows duplicates! Any suggestions about what's wrong?

Comment: We need a lot more context; especially the structure of $linkphoto

Comment: solved the problem by creating a new array from the page displayed. It seems that the current array is a little bit crapy!!

Comment: It is a good habit to show a failing test when you claim that something is not working. For writing tests in Php you cah use PhpUnit (http://www.phpunit.de/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/array_unique), the condition for equality is as follows:

> **Note:** Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same. The first element will be used.

What sort of data are you using? If two items aren't string equal, then they'll both remain in the array.

Comment: what shall i say i don't understand much PHP
my array is the same as something like that
array[1] = string
array[2] = string
i want to delete the duplicates if found

Answer (score 1):

We need more context in order to be able to help you, like what the contents are of `$linkphoto` before `array_unique` is applied to it. For example:

```
<?php
$array = Array('A','B','C','D','B');
print_r($array); // Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C [3] => D [4] => B )
$result = array_unique($array);
print_r($result); // Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C [3] => D ) 
?>
```

As @nobody_ mentioned, it will only eliminate duplicates if their string representations are the same.

Comment: normaly it should contain elements like the array above, but it's not currently acting like an array.
Anyway I found a solution by creating a new array and filling it with the $linkphoto